# SignalR Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: None of the transports supported by the client are supported by the server

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr, transport

I am trying to use SignalR in my .NET CORE 3.1 webapi(server) and angular 10(client) project. API (https://localhost:44305/api) and client angular (https://localhost:44305/user/signup) project shares same domain. This is how I have setup signalR in the server side:

1. I have created Hub class

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
   namespace Web.Hubs
   {
       public class ResponseHub : Hub
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. In Startup.cs class, added services.AddSignalR() in the ConfigureService method. And Enabled CORS like :

   ```
               services.AddCors(options =>{
                   options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                   builder =>
                   {
                       builder
                       .WithOrigins(Configuration.GetValue<string>("https://localhost:44305"))
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials();
                   });
               });
   ```

   And added following lines in configure method :

   ```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
              {

                  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                      name: "default",
                      pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                  endpoints.MapHub<ResponseHub>("/userdetails/response");
              });
   ```

In the client side,

1. I have installed "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.9" package in the angular project.
2. created service for the signalR like :

   ```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
   import { Signalrresponse } from "./signalrresponse";
   import { Router } from "@angular/router";
   import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr'; 

   @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class SignalRService{
       constructor(private router: Router){}
    public data : Signalrresponse;
    private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection
       public startConnection = () =>{
           this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                                   .withUrl("https://localhost:44305/api/userdetails/response")
                                   .build();
           this.hubConnection
               .start()
               .then(() => console.log("Connection Started"))
               .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
       }

       public addTransferChartDataListener = () =>{
           this.hubConnection.on('changestatus',(data)=>{
               console.log("Received data");
               this.data = data;
           })
       }
   }
   ```

I am getting an error while trying to establish a connection from the client side. Error message:

> Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: None of the transports supported by the client are supported by the server.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can add on the client side the protocol that you want to use and then use another protocol to see if it connects. Then if other protocol will work, now you will know what exact protocol is not working and enable it on the server.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/cient-side-signar-hub-connection-internals-5fdc. Is the right version installed?